# UITextView linkTextAttributes can not be set without app crash

Tags: swift, attributes, uikit

I have a problem with assigning link attributes to UITextView
I used to do it this way which has worked for me in other projects and it is not working now

```
let linkAttrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: R.color.scarlet()!, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle]

    policyFld.linkTextAttributes = linkAttrs
```

I think it should be done this way now

```
let linkAttrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: R.color.scarlet()!, NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle]

        policyFld.linkTextAttributes = linkAttrs
```

But Xcode can only compile with this option

```
let linkAttrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: R.color.scarlet()!, NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle.rawValue: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle]

    policyFld.linkTextAttributes = linkAttrs
```

However the whole text does not write out properly. In the places where the link should be, the linked text is not drawn out but I can click it.

When I open the screen with the text the app stops on a breakpoint issued by the app delegate and if i continue only the part of the text described is written out.

I will attach pictures

Without adding the link attributes the text looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Se1.png)

With the text attributes when I continue after the breakpoint it actually looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3cFh.png) the links are there and are active but I can not see them.

I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FxgX.png) and want to make this method work

UPDATE: 
In my app the swift version is 4.2 and linkTextAttributes is [String : Any]

Comment: There is a crash? What's the crash error message? You are using an old version of Swift. Note that `linkTextAttributes` depending on the version is either a `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]` or a `[String: Any]` which could explain the "rawValue" needed for the key.

Comment: @Larme it was actually not a crash, I updated the description of my problem and what I have tried even with some pictures. Do you know where the problem could be?